Sufficient condition for isotypic projector to be real
Definition: A representation $ \rho: G \to \mathrm{GL}(n ,\mathbb{C}) $ is called $\textbf{self-conjugate}$ if it is isomorphic to the conjugate representation $ g \mapsto \overline{\rho(g)} $ where the bar denotes the complex conjugate of the matrix (i.e. take the complex conjugate of each entry).
Suppose that $ \rho: G \to \mathrm{GL}(n ,\mathbb{C}) $ is a representation of a finite group $ G $. Now suppose that $ \chi $ is an irreducible character of $ G $ that is real-valued ($ \overline{\chi}=\chi $).
Consider the isotypic projector onto the $ \chi $-isotypic subspace of $ \rho $ (normally the $ \chi(g) $ in this formula would be $ \overline{\chi(g)} $, but since $ \chi $ is real valued it doesn't matter)
$$
\Pi_{\rho,\chi}=\frac{\text{deg}(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) \rho(g)
$$
Is the fact that $ \chi $ is real valued and $ \rho $ is self conjugate sufficient to guarantee that the projector $ \Pi_{\rho,\chi} $ is real? In other words,
$$
\overline{\Pi_{\rho,\chi}}=\Pi_{\rho,\chi}
$$
Note that if there exists some $ g_0 \in G $ such that $ \rho(g_0) \rho(g) \rho(g_0)^{-1}=\overline{\rho(g)} $ for all $ g \in G$ then we indeed have
$$\begin{align*}
\overline{\Pi_{\rho,\chi}}&=\frac{\text{deg}(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) \overline{\rho(g)} \\
&= \frac{\text{deg}(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) \rho(g_0) \rho(g) \rho(g_0)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{\text{deg}(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) \rho(g_0 gg_0^{-1})  \\
&= \frac{\text{deg}(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g_0^{-1}gg_0)  \rho(g) \\
&= \frac{\text{deg}(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g)  \rho(g) \\
 &= \Pi_{\rho,\chi}
\end{align*}$$
This observation is relevant, for example, if the image of $ \rho: G \to \mathrm{SU}(2) $ contains $ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix} $ since then we can take $ \rho(g_0)= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix} $ and then
$$
\rho(g_0) M \rho(g_0)^{-1}=\overline{M}
$$
for every $ M \in \mathrm{SU}(2) $.
To reiterate, the question I am asking is: if $ \rho: G \to \mathrm{GL}(n ,\mathbb{C}) $ is  self-conjugate and $ \chi $ is real then must the projector $ \Pi_{\rho,\chi}=\frac{\text{deg}(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) \rho(g) $ be real?
If $ n=1 $ this should be true because of the identity $ \sum_{i=1}^k \zeta_k^i =0 $. For $ n=2 $ you can check alot of cases using the observation I described above about $ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix} $ and indeed $ \Pi_{\rho,\chi} $ is real. Perhaps for $ n>2 $ there is an easy counterexample? Or maybe I missed a counterexample for $ n=2 $? Also of course if $ \rho $ is real valued then $ \Pi $ will be real.  So one way to think about the interesting case here is we want $ \rho $ self-conjugate but not real in any basis (e.g. Frobenius-Schur indicator $ -1 $) and we want to see if the projector is still real not just for real representations  but also for symplectic representations.

Because $\chi$ is realvalued, the associated irrep is self-conjugate, hence the $\chi$-isotopic component of any finite-dimensional representation will also be self-conjugate (being a finite direct sum of copies of the irrep associated to $\chi$.)
Write $V=\Bbb C^n$ (considered as the vector space on which $G$ acts via $\rho$) as a direct sum $V=V_{\chi}\oplus W$, where $V_\chi$ is the $\chi$-isotopic component and $W=\ker(\Pi_{\rho,\chi})$, which is also a subrepresentation (because $\Pi_{\rho,\chi}$ is $G$-equivariant). Then a simple character computation (or a direct argument) shows that $W$ must be self-conjugate as well. Choose isomorphisms $f:V_{\chi} \to \overline{V_\chi}$ and $g:W \to \overline{W}$, then by construction $f\oplus g: V\to \overline{V}$ is an isomorphism. Now identify $V=\Bbb C^n$ with $\overline{V}$ as vector spaces and sets and represent $f\oplus g$ by a matrix $A$. Then I claim that $A$ commutes with $\Pi_{\rho,\chi}$. But this is clear because $f\oplus g$ respects the subspace decomposition $V=V_\chi\oplus W$ and $\Pi_{\rho,\chi}$ is the identity on $V_{\chi}$ and zero on $W$.
Because $A$ defines an isomorphism $V \to \overline{V}$, we have $A\rho(g)A^{-1}=\overline{\rho(g)}$ for all $g \in G$. Now we can do a similar computation to the one you did:
\begin{align*}
\overline{\Pi_{\rho,\chi}}&=\frac{\text{deg}(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) \overline{\rho(g)} \\
&= \frac{\text{deg}(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) A \rho(g) A^{-1} \\
&=A \left(\frac{\text{deg}(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g)  \rho(g)\right) A^{-1}\\
&= A\Pi_{\rho,\chi}A^{-1} \\
 &= \Pi_{\rho,\chi}
\end{align*}
